# Vim sync syntax from beginning of file on command

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

When working with HTML with embedded Javascript, the syntax highlighting often gets out of sync.  If I tell vim to always sync from the beginning of the file, navigation is too slow.  I was wondering if there is a way to tell vim *on command* to sync from the beginning of the file.  As in, "ok this is the code I'm working on, make it look right".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon this would work:

```
:syn sync fromstart
```

but maybe you omitted some conditions/criteria from the question, why this is not eligible?

Alternatively, I suppose

```
:syn sync minlines=99999
```

should have a similar effect on most source files (hopefully for you!).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the highlighting shouldn't get out of sync that often.  I wonder whether it might help to specify different syntax rules for "html-regions" and "javascript-regions" in the same document.  Check `:h syn-region` and `:h syn-include` as well as the answer to this SO question:  [In VIM, how can I mix syntax/ident rules of both jinja and javascript in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968592/in-vim-how-can-i-mix-syntax-ident-rules-of-both-jinja-and-javascript-in-the-same)