# Gvim doesn't highlight syntax correctly, how to fix it?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have a HTML file which contains both HTML and JavaScript. When I folded some code snippets, the syntax highlight didn't work well. Screenshot as following:
[image]

Line79 function setColor(color) is not correctly highlighted. Is there any way to fix it?

BTW, I am using GVIM 7.2 in windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Question:  Are you saying that everything is highlighted properly when the code is unfolded?

Comment: @Herbert, yes, if code is unfolded at the very beginning, everything goes well.

Comment: That points to it being purely a synchng problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:syn sync fromstart`

(See also `help syn-sync-first`)

Answer (score 3):

When Vim opens an html file it applies html highlighting throughout the file.  When you have a separate language in the html file you need to define syntax regions to let Vim know that parts of the file are to be highlighted differently from the language identified by the file extension.  I described how to do this in an answer to an SO question here:  [In VIM, how can I mix syntax/ident rules of both jinja and javascript in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968592/in-vim-how-can-i-mix-syntax-ident-rules-of-both-jinja-and-javascript-in-the-same)

Also review the docs at `:h syn-include`.

Indenting is similar.  That is, Vim will apply html indenting rules to everything within the file unless you tell it to indent the Javascript region differently.

NOTE:  Maybe since html with embedded javascript is so common the html syntax files may by default support embedded javascript.  The tip linked below suggests using `:set filetype htmlm4` to get proper highlighting, although a commenter says that should not be necessary:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Syntax_highlighting_for_HTML_with_embedded_Javascript

Comment: I tried "set filetype htmlm4", vim prompts an error E518:unknown option: htmlm4

Comment: That's not the problem at all. The problem is purely with the synchronisation. This is regularly a problem if you start at the end of a document, code folding can also make it obvious.

Comment: @xiao -- That error means you don't have the htmlm4.vim file in your syntax directory.  I assume that file can be found somewhere on web (or in more recent version of Vim).  So you could try that.  BUT I think Chris's tip on synching is probably where your problem is.  If `:syn sync fromstart` fixes things then that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you have a line in the mapInit() function whose length exceeds vim's 'synmaxcol' setting  Notice the highlighting is incorrect on line 77 too (the closing brace).

```
set synmaxcol
```

From vim's help:

> Maximum column in which to search for
>   syntax items.  In long lines the text
>   after this column is not highlighted
>   and following lines may not be
>   highlighted correctly, because the
>   syntax state is cleared. This helps to
>   avoid very slow redrawing for an XML
>   file that is one long line.