# Edit multiple files in 1 vim buffer

Tags: python, ruby, vim

I'm making a vim script to take notes, and it should be tag aware.
So when I add a note it should appear under all the correct sections like this:

[image: example]

To avoid making lots of copies of the same text block and constantly scanning the buffer for changes, I'd like to just have one text file per note and open them in the correct sections. In this case it would open ~/notes/BFC49jl8.txt under "cat facts" and "anatomy" sections.

Then when I make changes everything should update just like editing any normal file, so if I delete a sentence it would update like:

[image: example2]

How do I open different files in 1 buffer? (or is there a better way?) Using python or ruby is fine.

UPDATE: I went ahead and implemented this without any data structure in vimscript. I'll optimize it with python later :) right now it only has very basic functionality but it covers my needs. [Github link](https://github.com/Corm/Tag-forrest).
[image: updated]

Comment: Cool! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is absolutely impossible because a buffer is the in-memory representation of a file. You can't have multiple files in one buffer.

It is easy to insert the content of another file in the current buffer with `:r` but, once the operation is done, no memory is kept of the origin of the inserted text so no syncing is possible.

If you need that feature you'll have to code it yourself and find a way to track and sync changes in that "main" buffer and the smaller files/buffers, essentially devising your own data structure in the process. This doesn't really sound trivial to me. And probably not something we could write for you in a quick answer.

Is there a specific reason why you don't simply use a single file/buffer for everything, like in org mode or some outliner? And, did you make some research before asking?

Comment: Oh yes, I've been trying to figure out how to implement this for a long time, and considered using syntax sections, autogenerated for each note, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968592/in-vim-how-can-i-mix-syntax-ident-rules-of-both-jinja-and-javascript-in-the-sam).

I didn't want to use 1 buffer/file for performance reasons, since scanning 10+ instances of notes, for each note, could be very taxing to regex. Thanks for the tip on org mode! I'll now try to get a handle on how vim does buffers behind the scenes.

Comment: After looking into this and reading the docs, it doesn't appear that you can do this in org mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might have success with [QFixHowm](https://sites.google.com/site/fudist/Home/qfixhowm), a port of the [howm](http://howm.sourceforge.jp/) tool for Emacs. Unfortunately most of the pages on it seem to be in Japanese, but I can sort of understand the Google Translate-rendered version of its home page.

Comment: Hey this actually looks like it does exactly what I was asking! I'll keep an eye on this and test it out.